# Foreach Split not looping

Tags: php, loops, foreach, split

Here is my code:

```
$entusername = "why,always,me";
$entusername = str_replace(' ', '', $entusername);
$sortusernames = split(',',$entusername);
foreach ($sortusernames as $eachuser){
echo "$eachuser<br>";
}
```

This code returns the following:

> whyalwaysme

however I'm trying to get it to echo like this:

> why
> always
> me

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Works fine: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8v7-eqp.  By the way use `explode` instead of `split`, `split` is deprecated as of PHP '5.3.0'.

Comment: Check your sourcecode maybe to be sure of the output of your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you are preprocessing it and running it on a browser it shows

why

always

me

If your running it in the command line i.e. `$ php yourfile.php`  - you might want to use PHP_EOL

```
echo "$eachuser" . PHP_EOL;
```